# Adding variables to unix command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Pardon me as I am relatively new to this.

```
[ -f /etc/example/txt] && echo "True" || echo "False"
```

I have the above code, I am trying to print out the hostname as well.

I have modified it to the following,

```
[ -f /etc/example/txt] && hostname = uname -n &&echo "$hostname:True" || echo "$hostname:False"
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work. Is there a way to have the hostname printed out along with True or False?

Comment: `hostname="$(uname -n)"; if [ -f /etc/example/txt ]; then echo "$hostname:True"; else echo "$hostname:False"; fi`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
 [ -f /tmp/txt ] && [ $hostname = $(uname -n) ] && echo "$hostname:True" || echo "$hostname:False"
```

Comment: This won't work the way you think it will... 
When you define hostname don't preceed it with a "$".  
No spaces around the "=" sign.  
If /tmp/txt isn't a file it will skip to "echo "$hostname:False" which won't have the variable $hostname defined.

Comment: `sHostName=$(uname -n) && [[ -f /tmp/txt ]] && echo "$sHostName:True" || echo "$sHostName:False"`